# How to add hyphen to regex

Tags: php, regex

I have encountered this pattern

```
(\w+)
```

and from http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ site I understand that `\w` = match alpha-numeric characters and underscores, and `+` = match previous token 1 or more times (not exactly sure what that means).

How can I add the hyphen character to the list?

I tried `(\w\-+)` but it doesn't work, I don't get any match ...

Comment: Note that U+002D is really `HYPHEN-MINUS`, and that U+2010 is the real `HYPHEN` character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a character class, denoted by `[...]`. `\w` can then be used in the character class and more characters can be added:

```
[\w-]
```

Careful though, if you add more characters to match. The hyphen-minus needs to be *first* or *last* in a class to avoid interpreting it as a range (or escape it accordingly).

The `+` is a quantifier, so it goes after a token (where the whole character class is a single token [as is `\w`]):

```
([\w-]+)
```

Comment: Capturing groups can be pretty useful.

Comment: If `(\w+)` is the complete regex, then you don't need a group, as the match alone suffices.